# Synchronizing NSMutableArray for Thread Security ?

Tags: iphone, synchronization, locking, nsmutablearray

I have a Threaded application, in which there is a `NSMutableArray`, which contains the `NSManagedObjects`, Now i want my array to be accessed once at a time by any Thread. So how do i synchronize that array, or may be put locking mechanism on it.

Thanks in Advance ...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could wrap every access to the class with something like the following:

```
@synchronized(myArray) {
  [myArray doSomething];
}
```

Comment: While this solution works - it is probably the slowest way to synchronize writes to the array, plus it blocks the caller, so if you try to call from different concurrent threads, you actually force them to synchronize. Better dispatch the write to some asynchronous serial queue instead.