# What happens if NSMutableArray is modified by multiple threads at the same time? (if the objects it contains are retained elsewhere)

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutableArray containing many objects.

What happens if a change is made to the array, while I am making a copy of the array using [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:someArray];

Eg: If an object an object is removed from the array while the copy is being made?

I'm not sure how to test this scenario.

EDIT: The objects are not released (as they are retained elsewhere). I just use this array as a lookup table.

Comment: I had a similar problem two days ago, but I was removing items from an array and enumerating in other. Got an exception about the array being modified. If arrayWithArray: uses fast enumeration (I don't know), it will throw an exception.

Comment: I think you understand my problem! I am trying to determine if an exception will be thrown. But I can't create a test to verify this as I can't coordinate another thread to modify the array while a copy is being made.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

as you know, the container/collection is not guaranteed to be thread safe. what *could* happen if you change the array while copying or reading? a lot of things. the obvious cases are that it may be reallocating at the time, it may pass or return an invalid reference to you (e.g. the most recently removed), or it may access objects which have been released (from another thread). in addition to things that will make your app crash or cause other UB, it may not return correct or consistent values. it is a misinterpretation of the data. neither are good.

you don't *test* the scenario - threading issues are difficult to reproduce and you really can never cover all the cases. since the object itself does not guaranteee thread safety - your implementation has to restrict accesses/mutations/interactions to one thread at a time. when dealing with object which are used in multithreaded contexts: anytime you access or query information from an object's mutable state, you should guard the object (e.g. with a lock). therefore, you simply lock it while using it. *lock/copy/unlock/use copy* is also common. for an NSMutableArray, examples of mutable state would be all its objects and its count. its operations and mutations also use the object's mutable state, so they are restricted.

if you only use this object from one thread, then obviously don't need to lock it. this is also a reason why passing by copy and holding immutable variants are both good ideas in most cases. you don't need a lock for each object, a guard for the object which holds it is often a good way to design a class for thread safety.

**Update**

> ...What happens? Does the copy contain all 5 objects (since they are retained elsewhere anyway? Do they contain 4? (even containing 4 is sufficient for me) Is an exception thrown ?

if you have not properly guarded the collection, it's as good as undefined behavior and you're lucky if it crashes.

you need to take the appropriate precautions to avoid undefined behavior. your program is operating in that domain when it's not properly guarded.

to elaborate: retaining the objects externally only reduces the probability of undefined behave\ior, but it certainly does not eliminate it. more examples of consequences include exceptions, segfaults, reading or writing memory which is used as another active allocation (which may show up as very mysterious issues which may also be virtually impossible to reproduce).

i encourage you to guard properly or take another approach. UB is EVIL :)

Comment: As the objects are not being released by any thread, I am trying to understand what happens if an array is modified while [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:(NSMutableArray*)] is running. Eg: 1. If I have an array that has 5 objects (retained elsewhere as well). 2. Another thread tries to make a copy of this array. 3. A third thread modifies the original array (removes one object). 4. What happens? Does the copy contain all 5 objects (since they are retained elsewhere anyway? Do they contain 4?(even containing 4 is sufficient for me) Is an exception thrown ?

Comment: Too bad I can’t upvote again for the _undefined behaviour is evil_ update.

Comment: @Bavarious it's ok.. i did that for you! :)

Answer (score 5):

From Apple's [Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html):

> Mutable objects are generally not thread-safe. To use mutable objects in a threaded application, the application must synchronize access to them using locks. (For more information, see “Atomic Operations”). In general, the collection classes (for example, NSMutableArray, NSMutableDictionary) are not thread-safe when mutations are concerned. That is, if one or more threads are changing the same array, problems can occur. You must lock around spots where reads and writes occur to assure thread safety.

Also from Apple's [Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1):

> Although “atomic” means that access to the property is thread-safe,
>   simply making all the properties in your class atomic does not mean
>   that your class or more generally your object graph is
>   “thread-safe”—thread safety cannot be expressed at the level of
>   individual accessor methods. For more about multithreading, see
>   Threading Programming Guide.

Comment: I've read the apple docs, but it is unclear to me what actually happens in this scenario. As it is hard to get the two threads to perform the operations in sync, I can't see what problem will occur.

Comment: Check out the section: "Using the @synchronized Directive" in the threading programming guide. Also see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521190/synchronizing-nsmutablearray-for-thread-security

Comment: I know what @synchronized is used for. The guide talks about bad things that can happen when an object being accessed by one thread, is released by another thread. As my objects are not being released by any of the threads, what happens if an array containing references to an object, is modified while a copy is being made? I don't think there could be a "dangling pointer" scenario, because the objects themselves are retained elsewhere, so any pointer pointing to the object should be valid. what happens to this array, if it is modified when a copy is being made?

Comment: The short answer is to follow Apple's guidelines and you won't have to worry about this. Whether or not an exception will occur I cannot tell you, and based on the docs it sounds like Apple is saying all bets are off. Is there any good reason to not do this correctly?

Comment: For performance reasons, I do not want to synchronize the copy (if possible). Since it is only a read, and there is no intent to release the objects, I am wondering if I can do it. But since it is hard to test, I can't be sure.

Comment: My advice is to do it right and if you find that the performance is killing you then find another way to achieve what you are after. It is impossible to test what you are looking for since the results are undefined. This is a great example of why premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 0):

If removeObject is called at the same time as arrayWithArray, your program will crash. If you use synchronisation, forcing removeObject to be performed either just before or just after arrayWithArray, you can't know how many objects the new array will have. That won't crash immediately, but what is your code going to do? You have to be very clear in your mind that the result of [NSArray arrayWithArray:someArray] is an array that doesn't contain the contents of someArray right now, but the contents of someArray at some point in the past.